# Lavender's scent

Tags: flowers, lavender

Recently my lavender bloomed (supposed to be lavender angustifolia)
but there's no smell, the leaves however do smell when you rub them between your fingers.

Is it not a "scenty" lavender species? or does it take time for the flowers to actually produce any kind of scent?  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lavender is an aromatic plant and the flowers are scented; but they do not scent the air, both the flowers and the leaves have to be bruised or rubbed to release the scent, so if you were expecting to stand nearby and smell the lavender once in flower, you won't. *Lavandula augustifolia* is the main variety used to produce lavender oil, when both the flowers or flower buds and leaves are used, so they are fragrant.

Some plants do scent the air, things like Jasmine, honeysuckle, certain lilies or star jasmine, but many fragrant shrubs and herbs (thyme, sage) will only release their scent when bruised.

Comment: I always thought they do scent in the air - just like our jasmine.
thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You could try brushing against the shrub on a warm afternoon if you're sitting out there, that will release some scent briefly...