# Why does my rosemary stop giving out a fragrant?

Tags: indoors, herbs, rosemary

I bought a rosemary plant in a 15cm pot from a nursery last Sunday.  It was enclosed inside a big plastic bag when I cycled it home.

I could smell the fragrance when opened the plastic bag once in a while.  However, when I reached home and placed the plant near my window, I had to sniff it near to smell the fragrance.  The next few days, the fragrance disappeared but it is still there when I rubbed the leaves.  Since bringing it home, I did water it.

My room was recently painted and there was an odor from the enamel paint.  Did the paint fumes destroy my plant's ability to give out an aroma? Or what?

In the first place, how far should one be to smell the aroma?  I am feeling terrible as the whole point of buying it is to enjoy the fragrance in my room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should smell it when you rub or bruise it, so nothing seems to be wrong with your plant. When it was in the bag and it smelled when you open it, it was probably rubbed by the bag.

There was recently a similar [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/53268/lavenders-scent) answered by [Bamboo](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/1380/bamboo), where the OP asked the same for lavender.